# Missing required modules while running the dynamic library in another application

Tags: ios, libraries, carthage

```
carthage version: 0.16.2
xcodebuild -version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
Are you using --no-build? No
Are you using --no-use-binaries? No
Are you using --use-submodules? No
Structure of Cartfile
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.3
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 1.2
github "DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger" ~> 3.3
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"
github "krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift"
github "iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto"
github "ashleymills/Reachability.swift"
github "ViccAlexander/Chameleon"
github "Alamofire/AlamofireImage" ~> 2.0
github "akosma/SwiftMoment"
```

Above is the structure of my cartfile. I am creating a dynamic framework which contains all these frameworks. My dynamic framework got build properly. But when I use my dynamic framework in my app project I am getting the following error

```
Missing required modules : 

'Alamofire',
'XCGlogger',
'SwiftMoment',
'AlamofireImage',
'Chameleon',
'Reachability',
'IDZSwiftCommonCrypto',
'CryptoSwift',
'SwiftyJSON',
'ObjectMapper'
```

> Do I have to do anything extra to link my `carthage> build > ios frameworks` into my project?

Comment: @Krodak can you look on to this

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet? I am experiencing basically the same thing